# MS Visio 2013 swimlane issue

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

Hi This questions is about MS Visio 2013. Is there any way to split the first vertical separator so when I center the lane heading it is actually in the center? Also is there a way to equally separate vertical swimlanes? Thanks for your help